# Make a div.show/hide from insider button, but let the button stay

Tags: jquery, css

I have a left navigator that I want to make it hide on a user command.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ktqbz/

the "I hide the nav" button should stay visible after it is clicked staying at the same vertical space and reposition itself to the original location when the nav is shown again. How can I accomplish this? I can change the html if needed, I know that when you have `display:none`, none of its children will be displayed, the flow is also altered so the button wont stay in the same vertical spot. I can change the design too so if you have a better idea I'm all ears. However, this should be as friendly for the user as possible, if I move the button from its vertical spot, people might be confused, thats why I want to keep it there.

Comment: Here is a crude edit :): http://jsfiddle.net/Ktqbz/1/ .  This is just one of any number of solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is mainly with your markup. the "I hide the nav button" is contained withing #leftNavigator, so when you hide the #leftNavigator you are also hiding the button that you want to stay visible. There are a number of way to modify your markup to make this work.

Essentially I just created a wrapper for the navigator and positioned it relatively, and within it I positioned the "I hide the nav button" absolutely. I also added a top margin to the two control panel buttons so that they leave room for the "I hide the nav" button. There are a lot of ways of making this work.

```
#leftNavigator{float:left; width:100%; background-color:red;}
#top{height:150px; background-color:blue;}
#controlPanel{height:50px; background-color:gray;}
#tree{background-color:green;}
#content{overflow:auto; background-color:coffee;}
#btn{z-index:10;position:absolute;top:150px;}
​#navigator_wrapper{position:relative;height:150px;width:20%}
#controlPanel button {margin-top:25px;}
```

​

```
<div id="navigator_wrapper">
    <button id="btn">I hide the nav</button>
    <div id="leftNavigator">
        <div id="top">I have an image</div>
        <div id="controlPanel"><button>Other</button><button>controls</button></div>
        <div id="tree">I'm a jstree</div>    
    </div>
</diV>
<div id="content">
    I take all the space I want. Except for leftNavigator's space.
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

HERE is a jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/samisadaka/9c7va/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately this might not work on the real deal since heights are not fixed. I'll figure something out. However this answers the question I made.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different version of Joe's fiddle. It will preserve the blocking by just changing the opactiy.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ktqbz/1/

```
$("#leftNavigator").animate({
    "opacity" : 0.0
});
```

Comment: I want the right side of the page to fill all the space available.

Comment: @Roger My example allows this.  The navigation pane acts as it did before only with the button outside of the container and with a "floating" effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the issue moving the `<button>` outside of the `div`.

I fiddled with your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Cam3/

Basically, change your HTML to looke like this:

```
<button id="btn">I hide the nav</button>
<div id="leftNavigator">
    <div id="top">I have an image</div>
    <div id="controlPanel"><button>Other</button><button>controls</button></div>
    <div id="tree">I'm a jstree</div>    
</div>
<div id="content">
    I take all the space I want. Except for leftNavigator's space.
</div>​
```

Button will stay fixed where it is (since it's `position: absolute`) and not disappear with the `div`.